# Why is Zurb Foundation Equalizer removing my event listener?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to bind an event listener to the `postequalized.zf.equalizer` event that is fired from a dom element that has an [Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html) plugin attached.

Here is the basic HTML structure of the equalizer section of the page:

Then, underneath all the HTML on my page I bind to the event and start foundation:

```
$('.productHeader').on('postequalized.zf.equalizer', function() {
  console.log('heights updated');
});

$(document).foundation();
```

The event is never getting fired. I see the following in the [equalizer source code](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.equalizer.js#L63):

```
  /**
   * Removes event listeners if the breakpoint is too small.
   * @private
   */
  _pauseEvents() {
    this.isOn = false;
    this.$element.off('.zf.equalizer resizeme.zf.trigger');
  }

  /**
   * Initializes events for Equalizer.
   * @private
   */
  _events() {
    var _this = this;
    this._pauseEvents();
    if(this.hasNested){
      this.$element.on('postequalized.zf.equalizer', function(e){
        if(e.target !== _this.$element[0]){ _this._reflow(); }
      });
    }else{
      this.$element.on('resizeme.zf.trigger', this._reflow.bind(this));
    }
    this.isOn = true;
  }
```

As you can see, the `_pauseEvents` method removes all event listeners in the `.zf.equalizer` namespace, so my event obviously gets removed.

Is this intentional? How am I supposed to bind to any of the equalizer events if they get removed when the plugin is initialized? They would also get removed when the window is resized, so I don't think changing the order of my code is a valid solution.

Comment: Not sure if there is a method specific to that library, but since it's using jQuery's event handling methods (or similar looking library), you could try using the js native methods like  `addEventListener('postequalized.zf.equalizer',...)` which jQuery (or whatever library) cannot remove the listener as it wouldn't have a reference to the original function tied to the listener

Comment: But will the event still be recognized if it's triggered using jQuery's `trigger` method, or does it need to be triggered by some native js method?

Comment: It seems jQuery's `trigger` does not cause custom events to be triggered when added through `addEventListener`, so that may be out if `.trigger` is used to fire the events

Comment: Ok that confirms what I'm seeing as well. Thanks for your help.